# How to add Elevation to a QGIS 3.12 attribute table for shapefile points

Tags: shapefile, field-calculator, elevation, qgis-3

What code do I use in the Field Calculator of the Attributes Table within QGIS 3.12 to generate the elevation of shapefile points in feet?

Comment: None. You simply use `join attributes by location` (to add the elevation from a polygon DEM) or `set z from raster` (to add the Z value of a raster DEM). Unless you have other data and didn't tell us about it.

Comment: Add more detail to your question. According to the current information, I would say that: 1. Get a DEM (digital elevation model); 2. Use Band calculation on it to convert it to feet dimension (from meter); 3. After vectorize (polygonize) the raster; 4. Finally intersect the resulted polygon with your original shapefile data. Good luck!